# Open Questions in Time Series Analysis

Tags: time-series

What are some current open questions in time series forecasting?

Comment: sounds like a "big list" question

Comment: For time series analysis, there are a number of related but distinct learning tasks (time series regression/classification, forecasting, panel forecasting, time series annotation, outlier detection, among others) and various approaches to solve them. Maybe you can try to narrow down your question.